# Trapezoid problem.

Tags: geometry

Given Trapezoid ABCD with EF as median (Mid-segment)and with diagonals AC and BD with 2 points G and H as points of intersection of the median and the said diagonals ( G being the intersection of EF and AC and H being the intersection of EF and BD respectively)

if bases AB and CD as well as the median EF is given is it possible to solve for the dimensions of segment EH? keep in mind that it isn't said to be an isosceles Trapezoid.
[image]

Comment: What is meant by dimension of a line segment? I guess you mean length of a line segement.

Comment: A sketch would help.

Comment: sorry about that my net was so poor, here i made a rough sketch

Comment: @Susobhan yes i meant the length of segment EH. sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $AB=x$ and $CD=y$. It is a well-known fact that the parallel $IJ$ (with $I\in AD,J\in BC$) to the bases that goes through the point of intersection of the diagonals, $P$, has length
$$\frac{2}{\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}}=\frac{2xy}{x+y}$$
that is the harmonic mean of $x$ and $y$. This implies $IP=\frac{xy}{x+y}$. Moreover:
$$\frac{DI}{IA}=\frac{\frac{xy}{x+y}-\frac{y}{2}}{\frac{x}{2}-\frac{xy}{x+y}}=\frac{y}{x},$$
hence:
$$EH = IP\cdot\frac{DE}{DI} = \frac{xy}{x+y}\cdot\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{y}{x+y}}=\frac{x}{2}$$
as expected, since the triangles $DEH$ and $DAB$ are similar and $\frac{AD}{ED}=2.$